# Function not called with selector action

Tags: swift

I'm trying to handle tap gesture in an external UIViewController's class but my function was never called. Here is my 
code:

```
import SceneKit
import UIKit

class SceneManager
{
private let assetFolder: String
private let mainCamera: SCNNode
private let view: SCNView
private let scene: SCNScene

init(view: SCNView, assetFolder: String, sceneFile: String, mainCameraName: String, backgroundColor: UIColor) {
    self.assetFolder = assetFolder
    self.scene = SCNScene(named: (self.assetFolder + "/scene/" + sceneFile))!
    self.mainCamera = self.scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName(mainCameraName, recursively: true)!
    self.view = view
    self.view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    self.view.allowsCameraControl = false
    self.view.pointOfView = self.mainCamera
    self.view.scene = self.scene

    //PROBLEM BELOW
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

@objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("hello")
}
}
```

Here is my ViewController Class :
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let view = self.view as! SCNView
    view.showsStatistics = true

    _ = SceneManager(view: view, assetFolder: "art.scnassets", sceneFile: "EURO_COPTER.dae", mainCameraName: "camera", backgroundColor: UIColor.blackColor())
}
}
```

If someone has an idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add : self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: Can you add the code of viewController where you are creating object of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this way:-

When you declare your class, add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` after the class it subclasses. Here's what that looks like in my case:

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true;
gesture.delegate = self
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
```

Comment: gesture.delegate = self  -> "cannot assign of type SceneManager to type UIGestureRecognizerDelegate" and userInteractionEnabled doesn't change nothing unfortunately.

Comment: I can't inherit from UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. I receive : "type SceneManager" does not conform to protocole NSObjectProtocol

Answer (score 0):

**Try following code it may help**

```
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SceneManager.handleTap(_:)))
```